# Flickering screen on hp elite book 830 g6

Tags: display, graphics-card, cpu, operating-systems, brightness

i am experiencing screen flickering even after updating my graphics card Intel UHD 620 i tried running my laptop with windows 10-11, Ubuntu but the problem still persist. but when i change the brightness to 100 it stops flickering, whenever i lower the brightness it starts flickering. can someone with an idea try help me solve this issue thanks

Comment: Did you use the latest [Intel driver](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/download/19522/intel-hd-graphics-driver-for-windows-10-64-bit-for-nuc8v7pn-nuc8v5pn-nuc8i3pn-for-windows-server-2019-and-windows-10-iot-enterprise.html?wapkw=UHD%20620)? Use a [clean install](https://community.intel.com/t5/Graphics/Intel-HD-620-Screen-Flicker-Issue/m-p/575147/highlight/true#M65542). You could also have a look at [this advice](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000026580/graphics/graphics-for-7th-generation-intel-processors.html).

Comment: yeah, my graphics driver is upto-date

Comment: Try again with a clean install. You could look at the linked article to see if the advice is useful.

Comment: yeah i  have done clean installation of my drivers. I think the drivers dont solve my problem even when i have the default os graphics driver the screen still flickers

Comment: Given that it also happens in Ubuntu, you're probably right that this isn't a driver problem. But in this case, we are left with a hardware problem, where a repair-shop would be more useful.

Comment: i dont get it when the brightness is 100% the screen dont experience flickering its only when its below, its really confusing to get the source of the problem, since i shipped my laptop and its still new. i thought it was brightness change but i tried coding a c# uwp app that changes my brightness every 1ms but it didnt help or show any brightness change, the problem looks mysterious to me what might be the cause? might be the cpu or a failing hardware, or the graphics card itself?

Comment: If the laptop is new, it's probably still under warranty. I would suggest to contact the vendor Support team and complain. If this is a hardware problem, you might be entitled to an exchange or at least repairs.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136805/discussion-between-ronald-saunfe-and-harrymc).

Comment: Does it still happen in the UEFI settings screen before loading the operating system?

Comment: yeah at times, the screen flickers a little bit which is quite unnoticeable

Comment: the screen also is showing anomaly sometimes it works fine but sometimes it decides to flicker i am confused whether its hardware or software at this point

Comment: Is the issue happening in BIOS (likely F9, F10, F11 historically on HP's)? That will confirm if its hardware & in that case I'd usually recommend warranty, but that sounds like its not possible. They'd likely have to replace the LCD which is actually TERRIBLY hard, but I am not 100% sure that is the cause, but it is very very likely
It could ALSO be the LCD cable. Does the flickering occur/stop when the lid is moved or in a certain position?

Comment: There are two different models when I searched HP's site for: 830 G6, x360 830 G6. Assuming its the first one here is the manuals section which we are focused on the 'service' manual:
https://support.hp.com/us-en/product/hp-elitebook-830-g6-notebook-pc/26609813/manuals

Direct link:
http://h10032.www1.hp.com/ctg/Manual/c06357078.pdf

pg65 shows how to remove the display assembly (lid). However pg67 shows how to remove the plastic bezel around LCD screen which may be all that you need to do to gain access to some screws to remove LCD & install replacement.

Comment: when the screen is positioned at different positions it doesnt affect the flickering, the screen flickers when typing using the keyboard or minimize/maximize an app at a time it wasn't flickering and at times the problem will go away, at times too without any activity it may flicker too. The manual is useful and shall be bigger risk and my final choice

Comment: is there a software for troubleshooting the  hardware health to check if there is an issue with the components

Comment: There isn't. The most you can do is search the Event Viewer for hardware-related error messages with some additional information, but the chances are low for finding useful info.

Answer (score 0):

Given that it also happens in Ubuntu, probably this isn't a driver
problem, so is very likely a hardware error that we can hardly
help with.

The computer is new, but bought in USA and you are in Kenya,
so using the warranty is somewhat problematic, unless there is
an HP vendor in your city that can help or honor the warranty.

The most you can do is search the Event Viewer for hardware-related
error messages with some additional information, that might help
pinpoint the error area, but the chances are low for finding useful info.

Or, in the hope that the problem is some contact that was jarred loose
when shipped, you could open the case and look for it, and just press
on any contact that looks suspicious.